# Property 'form_blocks' does not exist on type 'GanttStatic'

Tags: reactjs, gantt-chart

I have isse when I want to implement multi select input in my project react typescript.

**Property 'form_blocks' does not exist on type 'GanttStatic'.**
[image: block]

how to fix it.
could any one help me please

```
gantt.form_blocks['multiselect'] = {
  render: function(sns) {
    var height = (sns.height || '23') + 'px';
    var html =
      "<div class='gantt_cal_ltext gantt_cal_chosen gantt_cal_multiselect' style='height:" +
      height +
      ";'><select data-placeholder='...' class='chosen-select' multiple>";
    if (sns.options) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sns.options.length; i++) {
        if (sns.unassigned_value !== undefined && sns.options[i].key == sns.unassigned_value) {
          continue;
        }
        html += "<option value='" + sns.options[i].key + "'>" + sns.options[i].label + '</option>';
      }
    }
    html += '</select></div>';
    return html;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved use add union any type.

[image]